# Distribute for loop iterations through threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

I want to compute nested loop with `n` threads:

```
for (i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++) {
            // do the job
        }
    }
}
```

I want to compute each loop operation with different thread. Let's call thread `T`. With `3` threads and `matrix.size() = 5` this is how work should be distributed:

```
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=0 k=0
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=0 k=1
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=0 k=2
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=0 k=3
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=0 k=4
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=1 k=0
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=1 k=1
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=1 k=2
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=1 k=3
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=1 k=4
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=2 k=0
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=2 k=1
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=2 k=2
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=2 k=3
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=2 k=4
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=3 k=0
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=3 k=1
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=3 k=2
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=3 k=3
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=3 k=4
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=4 k=0
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=4 k=1
T[1] computes operation i=0 j=4 k=2
T[2] computes operation i=0 j=4 k=3
T[0] computes operation i=0 j=4 k=4
T[1] computes operation i=1 j=0 k=0
T[2] computes operation i=1 j=0 k=1
T[0] computes operation i=1 j=0 k=2
T[1] computes operation i=1 j=0 k=3
T[2] computes operation i=1 j=0 k=4
T[0] computes operation i=1 j=1 k=0
T[1] computes operation i=1 j=1 k=1
T[2] computes operation i=1 j=1 k=2
T[0] computes operation i=1 j=1 k=3
T[1] computes operation i=1 j=1 k=4
T[2] computes operation i=1 j=2 k=0
```

I managed to change last line to: `for (k = PROCESSINDEX; k < matrix.size(); k += PROCESSAMOUNT)`, but in result this is how work has been distributed:

```
T[0] computed 25 iterations
T[1] computed 50 iterations
T[2] computed 50 iterations
```

How can I improve that?

Comment: Why should it be distributed this way? Try to distribute by parallelizing the `i` loop, at most `j`. TBB would solve this problem for you without trying to write your own thread pool, and definitely more efficiently.

Comment: *How can I improve that?* Hard to say. What work you are assigning and how you are assigning it to the threads has not been documented in the question. A [mcve] would probably be very helpful in getting your point across. With a good code example you might be able to take advantage of [Code Review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: Some things to consider: 1) There is an overhead of creating an maintaining threads. 2) There is no guarantee that each thread will be on a different core or processor, the OS could schedule them serially on the same core. 3) You will need to add code for "joining" the threads when finished.

Answer (score 3):

Although in many practical tasks like multiplying two matrices, breaking it further down most probably will result in performance degradation because it will break memory locality for threads, if the tasks you do really have low data dependency, there is an obvious solution: you just enumerate all triplets `(i,j,k)` from `0` to `n^3-1` (assuming `n = matrix.size()`) and then spit that range in 3 almost equal chunks and pass them to each thread. Then each thread can easily reconstruct it's part of work (the task #`t` corresponds to `i+j*n+k*n^2` so:

```
i = t % n
j = (t/n) % n
k = t / n /n
```

Another solution is to use a thread pool and a queue for tasks. You don't assign each thread all the work at the start. You put the work into a queue and let each thread get some batch of work from it, when the batch is processed, get back and take the next batch from the queue and using batches reduces concurrency conflicts at the queue. The advantage of this approach is that if the time to process data depends on specific data, then you will balance actual work performed rather than number of tasks performed.